# Select count of users registered in each month

Tags: sql, postgresql

Having a very simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  registered TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT users_pk PRIMARY KEY (name)
);
```

How to select the number of user registrations in each month e.g.

```
Jan 2010 - 19,
Feb 2010 - 0,
Mar 2010 - 7
```

Comment: Why you are using TIMESTAMP datatype in REGISTERED Column ?

Comment: @Ahmed - why shouldn't they? Postgresql's `Timestamp` data type is for recording a date and time value. Maybe you're thinking of SQL Server's `timestamp`, which would indeed be inappropriate, but the question is tagged PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get those zero entries you need to join across `generate_series`:

```
select 
  to_char(gen_month, 'Mon YYYY'),
  count(name)
FROM generate_series(DATE '2010-01-01', DATE '2010-04-01', INTERVAL '1' MONTH) m(gen_month)
LEFT OUTER JOIN users 
ON (registered BETWEEN gen_month AND gen_month + INTERVAL '1' MONTH - INTERVAL '1' DAY)
GROUP BY gen_month;
```

You can make it a bit prettier by using `date_trunc`, but then you can't use a regular b-tree index on `registered`:

```
select 
  to_char(gen_month, 'Mon YYYY'),
  count(name)
FROM generate_series(DATE '2010-01-01', DATE '2010-04-01', INTERVAL '1' MONTH) m(gen_month)
LEFT OUTER JOIN users 
ON ( date_trunc('month', registered) = date_trunc('month', gen_month) )
GROUP BY gen_month;
```

If you want to pretty-print your output exactly as you wrote it, you could replace the `SELECT` clause with:

```
SELECT format('%s - %s', to_char(gen_month, 'Mon YYYY'), count(name))
```

Comment: Very good point, I will try it. But you have hardcoded the dates (in generate_series) - can they be a param? (i.e. I will query the DB about these stats from the last 12 months)

Comment: @Yanko Yes, you can write subqueries or query params. They're only hardcoded because you didn't provide real sample data to work with.

Comment: thanks, good to know this. One more question: what does the `m(gen_month)` part do?

Comment: @Yanko It's a table alias that gives the generated series table and its single column a name, so you don't have to refer to it by the function's name elsewhere. It looks confusing if you write `to_char(generate_series, 'Mon YYYY')`; much less weird to give the series an alias.

Comment: ah, great, so `m` can be any name (of table) and `gen_month` any name of column? (`m` is cryptic ;) )

Comment: @Yanko Yeah, it's kind of awkward when you need to give the table name (that you don't care about) an alias in order to give the column (which you do care about) a useful name. The alternative to a throw-away short table name is to use quite redundant naming like `genmonths.gen_month`.

Comment: is the time math correct? Doesn't it return dates shifted by a month?

Comment: @Yanko Hard to say. You didn't give sample data and matching expected results. Maybe you meant dates in arrears not advance. Up to you from this point.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MONTH(registered),YEAR(registered),COUNT(name),
FROM users
GROUP BY YEAR(registered), MONTH(registered)
```

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't have a `month` function; you'd use the SQL-standard `extract(month from registered)` or the Pg-specific `date_part` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script by months.

```
select
   to_char(date_trunc('month', registered ), 'MM') as month, -- or hour, day, week, month, year
   count(1) 
from
   member 
where
   registered >= '2010-01-01' 
   AND registered <= '2010-12-31' 
group by
   month 
order by
   month asc;
```